# What is the purpose of [TempData] in this project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to decipher a project hosted in github. The `[TempDate]` attribute in [this line](https://github.com/bhrugen/Spice/blob/275c8590518c99cc124d50d9914cce272f0acf3a/Spice/Areas/Admin/Controllers/SubCategoryController.cs#L22) seems to be trivial because its existence does not have any effect.

## Question

If I am wrong, what is the purpose of that `TempDate`  attribute in this project? And as it is not a Razor Page project, how can I access `StatusMessage` property of `SubCategoryController` class from within `Index.cshtml`?

## Edit 3

I try accessing `StatusMessage` from `View.cshtml` via `@TempData["StatusMessage"]`  but it does not render anything.

## Edit 3.1

```
<!-- Index.cshtml --->
<p>@((string)TempData["StatusMessage"])</p>

// HttpPost Create action method of SubCategoroyController

await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
StatusMessage = "Success";
return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));

// ConfigureServices of Startup.cs
services.AddSession();   
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

//  Configure of Startup.cs
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseSession();
```

## Edit 3.14

The following works but it is not what I want. I want to know the purpose of `[TempData]` attribute attached to the property `StatusMessage`.

```
// HttpPost Create action method of SubCategoroyController    
await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
TempData["StatusMessage"] = "Success"; // <==== Modified
return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First know that MVC uses razor. If it is MVC it is razor, and Index.cshtml is a a razor file. Anything with .cshtml is razor. So yes your project is a razor project

This attribute will add the class property "StatusMessage" to the tempdata dictionary.  To access it, simply call @TempData["StatusMessage"].  You will have to cast it to do any operations to it.

Keep in mind TempData lives for the current request, and the following request. Then it is removed.

To access the TempData when using the TempData attribute like mentioned above, use the key "TempDataProperty-StatusMessage".  It appends the "TempDataProperty-" to the key

Comment: @Gold Digging Programmer see the most recent edit.  When using Attributes it appends "TempDataProperty-" to the key

Comment: I will come back in 1 hour.

Comment: @Gold Digging Programmer  Yes I have tried it.  It may be different on your system.  I am using .NET core, because .NET framework is a dying framework.  I would put a break point in the Index.cshtml file where you are accessing the temp data, then in your immediate window call "TempData.Keys" to get a list of keys in the TempData dictionary.

Comment: Could you show your code as a github repo? I want to examine what your settings throughly. Thank you.

Comment: Some more info on that `TempDataProperty-StatusMessage` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.mvcviewoptions.suppresstempdataattributeprefix?view=aspnetcore-2.2 and also reference to it in an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7130